SotBit SEO умного фильтра: к странице фильтра не применяется ЧПУ
Сайт на Битрикс 1С. Подключен модуль seo умного фильтра от SotBit. Создавала условия согласно их видео и документации. Генерировала ЧПУ для условия тоже согласно документации.
Шаблон для новой ссылки /catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/{#PROPERTY_CODE#-#PROPERTY_VALUE#:/:-}/.
Но после активации ЧПУ ничего не происходит. Как был URL с filter и aplay, так и остался. При этом canonical подобных страниц уже прописывается корректный - согласно сгенерированному ЧПУ. Но если по этой каноничной странице перейти, то отдается 404 ошибка. В связи с чем может быть подобная проблема и в чем я могла допустить ошибку?
